# How can I delete/strip the white/blank rows in my csv file using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I had a csv file with information that had to be removed from it (did it by eliminating the corresponding columns) and the output I'm getting is what I expected except that is also giving me blank rows between each line. How can I get rid of those? (I currently don't have pandas, so it would be great if there's a solution to this without having to use it)

For example, I want to go from:

```
ssid vlan CT rssi date


#    #    #   #    #


#    #    #   #    #
```

To:

```
ssid vlan CT rssi date
#    #    #  #    # 
#    #    #  #    #
```

Here is the script I used to delete the columns I didn't want and also what is giving me those extra rows:

```
import csv

with open("SBU.csv","r") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader(source)

    with open("scrubbed.csv","w") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer(result)

        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow((r[0], r[1], r[3], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are running Python 3.X, you also have to include `newline=''` when opening the file in order to avoid adding any new lines in-between the rows you've been writing to the file. The following should do the trick:

```
with open("scrubbed.csv", "w", newline='') as result:
    wtr= csv.writer(result)
```